# Adding and Deleting between two seperate Array ListViews

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a custom `ListView`.

Initially, the custom `ListView` has one array of data, but when user taps one of the list items, it's then removed from current array and added to another. If the user taps on the second array, the list item is then added back over into the first array.

Please suggest how to apply logic to do this.

Updates : I wants to use only one listview/recyclerview.

*Following are screen shots..*

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: the object switching would be very easy, but that has nothing to do with the listview, is the purpose of this question to actually show the object switching groups? as in - clicking loads the list view with the other list and showing the object there?

Comment: yes sir, I want to remove from which user click and add to another group vise-versa. Like Phone contact list add to favorites and remove from it .

Comment: show your adapter and item's model class code, please

Comment: i have not implemented yet because with single listview no idea, i can delete item from listview and add it back , i have implemented this using two listview / recyclerview and two adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the object switch - this is a simple transfer between lists, , just know beforehand if the insertion and removal is index based, e.g:

```
contacts.add(iLocation, ContactObject);
favorites.remove(iOtherLocation);
```

Regarding the `ListView` stuff, I would suggest converting to `RecyclerView`, let's build a ***general*** scenario:

1. You have a screen (Activity or Fragment) that holds one list (the implementation can be `ListView` or `Recycler`), and another screen that holds the other list.
2. In both of your lists you have adapters in which you implement the logic for the clicks on the objects in the lists.
3. The click transfers the object, either directly to the other list, *OR* to a temporary Object holder (because you might need it for other stuff), in which case you will need to pull that object from the other view, either way you remove it from the current one.
4. you switch to the other view, and refresh it.

An easy way to go -

Assuming the screens are the same, use only one Activity, holding a single `RecyclerView`, and handle 2 adapters, each for every list, the adapters allow you to handle the clicks easily, with an index for the object clicked, the click executes the info swap action,the Activity handles the visual swap Action.

a **very general** example would be:

```
//init everything obviously ;)
List<ContactObject> contacts;
List<ContactObject> favoritesContacts;

//the AdapteListener is an interface declared inside the adapter
mContactsRecyclerAdapter = new ContactsRecyclerAdapter(this, contacts,new ContactsRecyclerAdapter.AdapterListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void cellClicked(int iIndex, ContactObject object)
        {
           favoritesContacts.add(iIndex, ContactObject);
           contacts.remove(iIndex);
           mContactsRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           mFavoritesRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(mFavoritesRecyclerAdapter, false);
        }
     });
```

And vice-versa for the other adapter.

Hope this helps, comment if you have problems and I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Please implements with custom view extend with Linearlayout

Custom view has 2 child Linearlayout in which will add with this custom view

First time add all the element in first Linearlayout and based on user action please remove from first Linearlayout and add it in another layout